# Перенос верстки landingpage bootstrap на Laravel без blade

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, laravel

Я сверстал сайт, одностраничник (landingpage), без Ajax, но с галереей на фреймворке Bootstrapv3.3.7 , для реализации адмики выбрал фреймворк Laravel v5.4.19.
Знаю, чтобы перенести верстку нужно обратить внимание на blade файлы и по отдельности их подключать,но я решил сделать файл index.php со всеми файлами верстки в папке Public, после данного деяния, я не смог зайти в админку по адресу http://localhost:8000/admin, я думаю проблема в том, что я не дописал код php на странице и не изменил файл .htaccess ?
Прошу помощи в данной проблеме

Comment: Без кода тут не разобраться.

Comment: роут для /admin имеется? И я честно говоря не особо понимаю чем Вам не угодил блейд, неужели пыхокод в одном большом файле вьюхи....

Comment: @KonstantinS, да имеется, не получается верстка на 1000 строк кода, разделил на 7 частей, перенес в блейды, там отказались работать стили и js компоненты, спрашивал в чате гиттера laravel,там ткнули в документацию, но из доков я не понял как побороть этот недуг